# A weekly community bounty for a random unanswered question?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

There are a lot of unanswered questions on Stack Overflow for which the asker doesn't have enough reputation to set a bounty for them.

How about each week, SO randomly chooses some of them and sets a bounty for them so these questions will be answered?

An unanswered question really doesn't mean it doesn't have an answer, maybe it left out or has been forgotten to check out and write an answer for it.

Comment: OR ... ALTERNATELY ... people could use the "unanswered" route more often. When's the last time you clicked "unanswered" on the tab bar up top and changed to that route to answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the bounty, [the Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) already randomly does this every hour:

> I'm a background process that helps keep Meta Stack Overflow clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - [...]

(For me, that's good enough.)

Comment: The difference between an human evaluation and best-practice or organizations stands in the effort to really evaluate if a contribution is bringing something positive or not. It's called evidence based.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience *most* people that have not enough reputation to set a bounty:

- ask very poor questions or
- can't figure out how to log in using the same account as last time or
- ask the question then don't seem to come back to read the answers

I'm not sure this is the sort of question we should be giving more attention. Those users who use the site properly will get enough reputation to set a bounty after not too long (100 reputation is not really that much) and so they can go back to their older questions and put bounties on them if they are still interested in getting them answered. That seems fine to me.